# Why object is necessary?

Tags: uml

I am weak in programming and may be that is why I am confused. And I am sorry if this question is off topic. The diagram shows how the table reservation will be made in restaurant. The boundary object is omitted in this diagram. The restaurant object has the responsibility of maintaining the complete set of reservation made for the restaurant. And it will create a new reservation object. It assumed that the data passed from the user contains textual identifiers for these objects, such as a table number and the name and phone number of a customer. This data would be entered by the user when specifying the details of the new reservation. Before the reservation can be created, however, we need to locate the objects identified by this data so that the appropriate object references are available when the new reservation is created. Each reservation object is linked to exactly one table and exactly one customer object? What I don’t understand is that it is really necessary to do like this in a very confused way. It is not enough with just database? There will be reservation table. Whenever user enter a new reservation, the table no and customer information will be entered in that reservation table. Why we need to know the objects?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because without knowledge of table and customer a reservation can not be completed. Of course you can leave out these objects and each time a reservation is made, you enter table number and customer name manually (e.g as strings '13', 'Mr. Miller'). But if you have this as object you can choose from them. So you have 13 table objects for your 13 restaurant tables. And when you make a reservation you see that it might already be occupied (rather than searching for a possibly mis-typed string in other reservations). If you have customer objects you can connect information with that customer like "Steak always rare").

Comment: Still for me, using the database table is simple. It is  just to add the constraint in the reservation table that the combination of  the columns of date, time, tableno must not be duplicate.

Comment: I'm afraid you should learn more about object oriented approach. It'll explain a lot of things that currently seem blurry to you like the usage of objects rather than flat programming in database.

Comment: Ok. I will learn more.  What does you mean object oriented approach here? Objectboriented programming?

Comment: Wow!I understand now. I can't  belive how much crazy I am. I was thinking that database will not be used because objects are used.

Comment: Hehe. The objects are mirrored in the database just for persistence. Or vice versa: to speed up access. Basically your DB-model is already sort of OO (if you did it the right way).

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule

> "If any method/notation  makes things
>   harder, do not use it.Use alternatives or even create your own home
>   made one"

This is a sequence diagram which shows "object" interactions at runtime to fullfill a goal.So there "are" objects not "classes": dynamic behaviour not static structure.

Be carefull

> Do not try to draw  sequence diagram (or any UML
>   diagram) for every object interactions.You should have a valid
>   "reason" for it and apply it for small subset of your problem space which is tricky or hard...

The main assumption is that

> UML will help you to investigating hard part of your  problem with the
>   help of visualization.

UML may fail to satisfy this. If this assumption does not valid for you, just FORGET UML. It is not a BIBLE...It is just simple drawing notation for to help us.